# 一人の彼女 versus 彼女の一人

Tags: grammar

Sometimes I find

> 一人の彼女

but sometimes I also find

> 彼女の一人

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend you reconsider before saying 彼女の一人 to your girlfriend, because `[noun] の (word means one)` means *one of [noun]*, so you're saying "one of girlfriends".

> cf. 自転車の一台、手紙の一枚、動物の一種、空き缶の一個、部屋の一つ

Conversely, 一人の彼女 is only a counter counting the noun, that means "one girlfriend". Your girlfriend might well be pleased with this one.

Comment: なるほど。有難うございました。