# What does のに比べて mean? In "一人の相手を幸せにするのに比べて"

Tags: particle-の, nominalization

> 一人の相手を幸せにするのに比べて、倍の時間を彼女のために使える必要があるはず

Compared to giving only one of your partner happiness, you need twice the time to make your partners happy.

- Is this の used as a nominalizer?
- Can の be replaced with こと?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That の is a nominalizer in the sense that it plays the grammatical function of turning the verb phrase 一人の相手を幸せにする into a noun phrase, just like the の in, say, 本を読むのが好きです.  However, the resulting noun phrase seems to have a more specific meaning than 一人の相手を幸せにする**こと**, which refers to the act of making one person happy in general and abstract terms.

Your sentence has no subject or topic, but we can assume it to be a person because of 使える. It’s *you* (or someone else) who must be **able to spend** twice as much time, not the act of making other people happy. For this reason, the following sentence would sound unnatural (to me, at least).

> （二人の相手を幸せにすることは）一人の相手を幸せにする**こと**に比べて、倍の時間を彼女のために使える必要があるはず。

This would compare one act against another, but the sentence would end up with a mismatching predicate.

The original sentence must be something like the following in its complete form.

> （（あなたが）二人の相手を幸せにする（ため）には）一人の相手を幸せにする**の**に比べて、倍の時間を彼女のために使える必要があるはず。

This basically compares two amounts of time or efforts. I would translate 一人の相手を幸せにするの as something along the lines of “the **time** you need to spend to make one person happy” and this translation is not possible with こと.

In comparison, the following seem both acceptable as the predicate is matching.

> （二人の相手を幸せにするのは）一人の相手を幸せにする**の**に比べて、倍の時間を要するはず。

> （二人の相手を幸せにすることは）一人の相手を幸せにする**こと**に比べて、倍の時間を要するはず。

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, this の is a nominalizer.
- Yes, this の can be replaced with こと.

So is this person talking about how to do 二股? Please always explain the context when you present a sentence based on an unusual context. Also, note that 一人の相手 here is "one girl", not "one of your partners" (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36012/5010)). Translating 相手 as "partner" is often misleading (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66456/5010)).

Comment: @aguijonazo ああ、この「の」をnominalizerでなく単なる代名詞と読むこともできますね…。でもnominalizerと読んでもいい気がします